# How to process Appfabric Service Bus Queues via Worker Role

Tags: azure, servicebus

I've a Azure Worker Role that currently processes the Azure Queue Storage by polling every x seconds.

given the Azure Storage Queue doesn't not gurantee FIFO, I would like to move the Queue storage to App Fabric Service bus.

Could ayone please show me or guide me how to perfrom get/put/delete of messages on App Fabric Service Bus Queue via worker role?

Also, which one of Azure Storage Queue and Service Queue is cost effective. We will be storing up to 9,0000 message in 15min.

Answer (score 0):

Please download this nuget package.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.Samples.PublishSubscribe

It contains get/put/delete examples using the new v1.5 sdk Service Bus.